# Problems using newpad with a size larger than the screen

Tags: rust, ncurses

I'm trying to scroll some text larger than the screen.

The docs say `newpad` is not limited by the screen size, but initiating it with values greater than the terminal available columns or lines fails to print anything:

```
newpad(LINES + 1, COLS); // fails
newpad(LINES, COLS); // works
```

Entire code for reference:

```
extern crate ncurses;
use ncurses::*;

fn main() {
    initscr();
    start_color();
    use_default_colors();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    curs_set(CURSOR_VISIBILITY::CURSOR_INVISIBLE);

    let pad = newpad(1000, COLS);

    refresh();
    let mut x = 0;
    while x < 1000 {
        x += 1;
        wprintw(pad, &format!("Line number {}\n", x));
    }
    prefresh(pad, 0, 0, 0, 0, LINES, COLS);
    getch();
    endwin();
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you *want* to happen and what *does* happen? "fails" and "works" are basically useless to those of us without a deep understanding of your program / ncurses.

Comment: Sorry, "fails" is a bit of a strong word. I mean it doesn't print anything.

Comment: This behaviour is confirmed. Fortunately decrementing the maximum extent of the viewport by 1 solves the problem as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior is a bit odd.

If the number of lines or rows is greater than the viewport, the last two `prefresh` arguments must be at most `LINES - 1` and `COLS - 1` respectively:

```
prefresh(pad, 0, 0, 0, 0, LINES - 1, COLS - 1);
```

If it's less, there's no need to subtract 1, as the code will work as expected.

Comment: It's not odd (see [manpage](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html)), but expected since those parameters are zero-based and in error conditions it says *"if the area to refresh extends off-screen"*.  With `LINES,COLS`, the area would extend off by one row/column.